# Should I submit a mixed theory-experimental paper to a computer science conference where most papers do not appear to include experimental results?

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science, paper-submission

I am considering submitting a (Computer Science) research paper to a conference. The paper contains both theoretical and experimental results. The call for papers of the conference that I am considering sending the paper to, says that it welcomes papers related to "theory, design, implementation, modeling, analysis, or application". But when I look through the papers submitted in the previous years (in order to better understand the sort of papers that get accepted), I do not find a single paper with experimental results. The results are all theoretical.

Does this mean that papers with experiments are not a good fit for this conference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different communities mean different things by "application."  In a very mathematical community, "application" may mean "figuring out what relevance this idea might have to something in the real world.  In a very industrial community, "application" may mean "has been deployed at industrial scale."  The relative scale of theory and application is also nicely illustrated in [this XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/435/).

I think that you are doing the right thing by looking at past proceedings and asking, "Are these people interested in talking about work like mine?"  This is important not just for getting your paper accepted, but also for the value that *you* will get out of the meeting, both in terms of the feedback you get and also in terms of what you can learn and the connections that you can build.

For a more efficient route to finding a good community, you can also talk to your advisor or other mentors you may have, who will likely know the communities better and readily be able to provide good suggestions about where to send your paper.

Comment: Or if the community is mathematical enough, "application" means "this can be used to study some other theoretical thing we are also interested in".

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ... implying a possibly fractal expansion of "purity" even within a single community. :-)